# Email current page button, include part of div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get not just the title and the url from my page when using the recomment by email button, but also part of the content.
I have this function:

```
        function emailCurrentPage(){
            var doc = window.document;
            var requested_div = document.getElementById('single_page');//the div is called single_page
            var requested_div_html = requested_div.innerHTML;
            window.location.href="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+escape(window.location.href)+doc.requested_div_html;
        }
        </script>
<a href="javascript:emailCurrentPage()"></a>
```

The issue is that I get `undefined` from `doc.requested_div_html`. Link and title work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it like this:

```
function emailCurrentPage(){
            var log = $('#single_page').find('p')[ 0 ];
            var requested_div = log.innerHTML;
            window.location.href="mailto:?subject="+document.title+"&body="+"URL Articol: "+escape(window.location.href)+" - Incipit articol:"+requested_div;
        }
```

I didn't need the doc element because it is already said  `window.location`

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that `doc.requested_div_html` is undefined, since you stored the HTML of the requested div in `requested_div_html`, not `doc.request_div_html`. It's just wrong variables.